# Calling additional function after a PHP ECHO triggering AJAX success

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Is it possible to have PHP call another "independent" function after returning the `echo` triggering the `success` part of my AJAX?

I have an AJAX call that waits for `echo "success"` from PHP, but whenever I add an additional PHP function after `echo "success"` my AJAX `success` does not trigger anymore.

```php
function myFunction($foo){
  // do something //
  echo "success";
  callToMyOtherFunction();
}
```

Comment: It should work if callToMyOtherFunction prints nothing via echo

Comment: Thank you, no echo but I have `return` . is it a problem ? possible to have a truly independent  call to the additional function ?

Comment: `return` should not be a problem. Look [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php) for information about the `pthread` php extension for threading